# PhpStorm is leaving blank line between two PHPDoc comments, how to solve it?

Tags: phpstorm, phpdoc, blank-line

[image]

PhpStorm is leaving blank line between two PHPDoc comments, I could not find it in settings.

Comment: What do you mean by "leaving"? Does it add it there on Code reformat or alike when you remove it. Or you have the blank line there and expect PhpStorm to remove it for you on Reformat?

Comment: P.S. 1) Try using **actual** PHPDoc comments -- they start with `/**`. The ones you are using are using comments but IDE understands them (for compatibility reasons). 2) try moving such comments **after** `use` clauses...